# Classification using Bernoulli classifier in Lingpipe

Tags: java, sentiment-analysis, lingpipe

I want to classify my data through bernoulli classifier in lingpipe
If someone has the working method for it, please share

Answer (score 0):

http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Natural-Language-Processing/LingPipe/com/aliasi/test/unit/classify/BernoulliClassifierTest.java.htm

I.e.

```
FeatureExtractor FEATURE_EXTRACTOR
    = new TokenFeatureExtractor(IndoEuropeanTokenizerFactory.INSTANCE);
...
BernoulliClassifier classifier
        = new BernoulliClassifier(FEATURE_EXTRACTOR);
```

Then use `handle()` to add training data, and `classify()` to get answers out.

---

To find this I googled on "Bernoulli classifier in Lingpipe" (without the quotes). I found the API docs, and saw no example usage and that it is poor quality. So, I guessed there might be a unit test, as Java programmers are quite anal about testing. So then I googled for "bernoulliClassifier lingpipe test" (again, without the quotes).

(By "poor quality" docs, I mean the function descriptions just repeat the function names, and add no information.)